# JQuery $.getJSON runs the first time, then never again

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a button click function that is to run a  $.getJSON when the button is clicked. It gets some values from a controller posts those to some form fields and opens a modal that contains the form.
The first time I click the button it runs the  $.getJSON posts the values and opens the modal just fine.
when i close the modal and click the button again. It just opens the modal and the values are the old values. It doesn't run the  $.getJSON again. I know it doesn't also because I put a break point in the controller. It hits the break point that first time. But won't go into the controller the other times until I completely reload the page.

here is my button click script

```
   $('[id^=edit]').button().click(function () {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    var arr = selected.split(',');
    var item = arr[0];
    var parent = arr[1];
    $("#itemspan").text(parent);
    $("#parentspan").text(item);
    $("#partno")[0].value = item;
    $("#parent")[0].value = parent;
    var url = $("#itemdetailsjsonurl").attr("href");
    var fullurl = url + '/' + item + '/' + parent;
    $.getJSON(fullurl, null, function (data) {
        $("#qty")[0].value = data.qty;
        $("#startdate")[0].value = data.sdate;
        $("#enddate")[0].value = data.edate;
        $("#notes")[0].value = data.memo;
    });

    $("#edtbomitem").dialog('open');
});
```

any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it gets cached by the browser. You can use the ajax stack of jQuery to set it off: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

> cache
>   Default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'
>   If set to false it will force the pages that you request to not be cached by the browser.

Grz, Kris.

Comment: This looks like it did it for me thank you! i just added       $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
before the getJson

Answer (score 0):

The click event has already fired so jQuery stops listening for the click.

Try: `$('[id^=edit]').button().live('click', function () {`

Comment: The even still happens because as i said the modal is opened again. just the get json was not working.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that after you get back your information from the server, you're not hooking up your button onclick event.

So either use the [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) syntax, or re-wire it up by hand after your call to the server.